# VBA returns "type-mismatch" when formula works just fine

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, type-mismatch

I have a macro that is supposed to return the value in column E if it matches the values in column A, column B, and column D.  The following formula entered into Excel works great:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A180="Category Name"),--(B1:B180="Specific Type"),--(D1:D180=2015),(E1:E180))`

But the following VBA program returns a "type-mismatch error".  The program is located as a module and not under a specific sheets.  I've verified that the "sheet name" ranges also exist.  Can anyone see what the mistake is?

For the record, columns a and b are text, and columns d and e are numbers.

```
Function LocateFirstCell()
Dim FirstCell

Dim ColA
Dim ColB
Dim ColD
Dim ColE

Dim Name As String
Dim BOD As String
Dim Year As Integer

Set ColA = Worksheets("Sheet Name").Range("A1:A180")
Set ColB = Worksheets("Sheet Name").Range("B1:B180")
Set ColD = Worksheets("Sheet Name").Range("D1:D180")
Set ColE = Worksheets("Sheet Name").Range("E1:E180")


Name = "Category Name"
BOD = "Specific Type"
Year = 2015


FirstCell = [SUMPRODUCT(--(ColA=Name),--(ColB=BOD),--(ColD=Year),(ColE))]
'=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A180="Category Name"),--(B1:B180="Specific Type"),--(D1:D180=2015),(E1:E180))

MsgBox ("FirstCell is " & FirstCell)
End Function
```

Comment: Both [.Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa175750(v=office.11).aspx) and [Year](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88k2aec8.aspx) are **reserved words**. It is never a good idea to repurpose reserved words unless for a very special reason (this isn't one of those).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use vba variables in the short hand of Evaluate; the `[]` is short hand for `ActiveSheet.Evaluate`

You must write it out and concatenate the variables into one string:

```
FirstCell = Worksheets("Sheet Name").Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(--(" & ColA.Address & "=""" & Name & """),--(" & ColB.Address & "=""" & BOD & """),--(" & ColD.Address & "=" & Year & "),(" & ColE.Address & "))")
```

Comment: You sir, are excellent and have my thanks!  While the formula as written still resulted in a "type mismatch error" I added quotation marks using Chr(34) around the Name and BOD variables and the formula now works.  Thank you again!

Comment: Ah yes they would be needed.  I will make the changes.  Could you mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.